# Laravel package development - overriding views from package is not working

Tags: laravel, package

I'm developing a Laravel package (Laravel 7.2) and can't figure out how to override a view from the package by the user.
When I publish the views and change the regular laravel view file, it still loads the package view.

My service Provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    $router = $this->app['router'];
    
    
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views', 'blog'); 
    //I tried putting this in the "register" method as well - changed nothing
    
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/resources/views' => resource_path('views/Packagename/blog'),
    ], 'views');

    


}
```

So if I run a view file, with something simple like this:

```
@extends("blog::layouts.layout")
@section("content")
<p>123456</p>
@endsection
```

Within the project it works fine.

If I run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=views
```

Then go to `resources/views/Packagename/blog`
change that same file and run the browser, nothing changes since it's still running the package view file and not the published one.

What am I missing here?

I know I can use something like:

```
view()->exists()
```

But doing that on every controller and on every include in the views seams kind of crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, I was doing it wrong. The file structure should have been: resources/views/vendor/packagename/
That works. Hope that helps.